# How to trigger the onclick event of a marker on a Google Maps V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I trigger the *onclick* event of a marker on a Google Maps from outside the map?

I use **version 3** of the API. I've seen many tutorials for version 2, but can't find this for version 3.

I have a global array (named *markers*) containing all the marker of the map (google.maps.Marker). Now I want do do something like:

```
markers[i].click(); //I know it's not working, but you get the idea...

//Next line seems to be the way in v2, but what's the equivalent in v3?
GEvent.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
```

Thanks for your help and if you need more info, let me know!

Answer (score 346, accepted):

I've found out the solution! Thanks to Firebug ;)

```
//"markers" is an array that I declared which contains all the marker of the map
//"i" is the index of the marker in the array that I want to trigger the OnClick event

//V2 version is:
GEvent.trigger(markers[i], 'click');

//V3 version is:
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
```

Comment: click is firing, but in my case info windows is not adjusting to the map, it cut down slightly.

Comment: @Saboor Awan Try to ask a specific question about this as comments are not the best way to sort this out.

Comment: This is is still correct.  Remember that jQuery also has a `trigger()` function.  In my case intellisense was popping up causing me to transpose the arguments.

Comment: Saboor Awan, try calling this function after some time (miliseconds) after the UI has been set (using setTimeout)

Comment: Doing this for v3 gives me `TypeError: a is undefined in main.js (line 16, col 894)` What would be the reason for that?

Comment: @invot Can't really help without seeing code, but I found someone with the same problem while doing a quick search... Try to set the "popupMapIn" width and height in CSS using pixels (px) and not percents (%).

Comment: That was what fixed it so long ago. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @AlexV where did you find that?

Comment: @Legionar Found what? The solution or the CSS error? The solution was found by debugging with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and the CSS main.js error was simply found by doing a Google search that lead me to [this post](http://gmap3.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=184).

Comment: @AlexV I already found out, what was the problem, it was my mistake in jquery... I had the same error "a is undefined in main.js on line 16"... it was not CSS error, but mine `markers[i]` has undefined index `i`...

Comment: There's a "trigger" event on GMaps V3, just like the one on JQuery: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: @AlexV How can I call trigger at center of map screen. I want that whenever button is pressed , marker is placed at center of map. So how to do that

Comment: @AlexV how can i pass arguments any idea?

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju See the [google.maps.Marker documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) on how to create markers

Comment: This solution does not work in clustered markers (one of the group markers) situation. Please share suggestion if you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

For future Googlers,
If you get an error similar below after you trigger click for a polygon

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vertex' of undefined"
```

then try the code below

```
google.maps.event.trigger(polygon, "click", {});
```

Comment: You saved my night. I was struggling for 3 hours on this! Thank you!!