# google maps trigger click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

```
$(document).on 'click', '#sideBar li', ->
    markers[$(this).data('marker')].panTo()
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[$(this).data('marker')], 'click')
```

Seems silly.  All answers point to this working perfectly.  My map pans to the appropriate marker, but I can't seem to get the 'click' action to happen to open the infowindow.  I'm using the new v2 of the gmaps4rails gem, which is where the `.panTo()` comes from.

Since it pans just fine, I'm inclined to believe that my `markers[$(this).data('marker')]` marker call is fine.

[answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730929/how-to-trigger-the-onclick-event-of-a-marker-on-a-google-maps-v3/2731781#2731781)
[answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794405/trigger-google-maps-marker-click)

Comment: I suspect your assumption is wrong.  A [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker) doesn't have a panTo method.

Comment: using the gmaps4rails gem, it does =)

Comment: Perhaps you should indicate that in your question.

Comment: sorry.  I'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the marker js object is a wrapper around the real google marker.

This enables to add extra methods.

If you need access to the google marker, just call `getServiceObject` function
method.

This is what you need:

```
googleMarker = markers[$(this).data('marker')].getServiceObject()
google.maps.event.trigger(googleMarker, 'click')
```