# How to Trigger Google Maps Marker From Outside of Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

**I have this HTML:**

```
<ul class="google-map__trigger">
<li data-id="marker-1" class="google-map__trigger-item">Trigger Marker 1</li>
<li data-id="marker-2" class="google-map__trigger-item">Trigger Marker 2</li> 
</ul>
<div id="google-map" class="google-map"></div>
```

**I have this JS:**

```
// Infowindow, latitude, longitude
var locations = [
    ['<div class="google-map__infowindow"><h4>Lervig Brygge</h4><p>Her ligger Lervig Brygge.</p></div>', 58.96746,5.765269],
    ['<div class="google-map__infowindow"><h4>Regn</h4><p>I denne rundkjøringen regner det. Det regner alltid i denne rundkjøringen. Det er litt av et naturfenomen!</p></div>', 58.96579,5.759518]
];

// Icons are located in this folder
var iconURLPrefix = '/_themes/prototype/graphics/icons/';

// Icons are named
var icons = [
    iconURLPrefix + 'location.svg',
    iconURLPrefix + 'weather-rain.svg',
]

// Map options
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'),
    {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.966222, 5.762930),
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 200
});

var marker;
var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon : icons[iconCounter]
});

markers.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }

    })(marker, i));

    iconCounter++;

}

function AutoCenter() {
    // Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // Go through each...
        $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });
    // Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
AutoCenter();
```

How can I trigger my map markers from outside of the Google Map, using the list in the HTML above? I have seen different ways of solving this, but I haven't managed to make it work with my code...

Appreciate any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger the onclick event of a marker on a Google Maps V3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730929/how-to-trigger-the-onclick-event-of-a-marker-on-a-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Are you using (or can you use) JQuery?

Answer (score 6):

Ref: [How to trigger the onclick event of a marker on a Google Maps V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730929/how-to-trigger-the-onclick-event-of-a-marker-on-a-google-maps-v3)

```
//using the index provided by jquery.each()  
$('.google-map__trigger-item').each(function(i){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    });
});
```

or, if they are in no particular order

```
//using your id data attribute
$('.google-map__trigger-item').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        var id = parseInt($(this).data('id').split('-')[1]) -1;
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 2019:**
Here's a vanilla version with some ES6 syntactic sugar.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.google-map__trigger-item')].map((el, i) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution requires JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Like so (no external library required):

## HTML

```
<ul class="google-map__trigger">
  <li data-id="marker-1" class="google-map__trigger-item">
      <a onclick="OpenInfowindowForMarker(1)">Trigger Marker 1</a></li>
```

## Javascript

```
function OpenInfowindowForMarker(index) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[index], 'click');
}
```