# How to perform click event on Google map maker automatically (without clicking on the marker)

Tags: google-maps-markers

Is there any way to perform marker click event on Google Map automatically.

Hope to hear from your answer.

Thank you.

Regards,

Parmanand Soni

Comment: Duplicate of [How to trigger the onclick event of a marker on a Google Maps V3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730929/how-to-trigger-the-onclick-event-of-a-marker-on-a-google-maps-v3/2731781#2731781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `google.maps.event.trigger()` method. See google docs [events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener). As an instance object you have to use your marker. For example:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
```