# How to reference a google map marker by it's id and activate it's click event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, maps, marker

I am dealing with Google Maps here and javascript.  I have an existing marker on my Google map and I can click on it and it displays a div.  If I click it again, the div disappears.  I gave this marker a specific, unique id.

There is also a Polygon on the map.  I want when the user clicks on the polygon that the click event is activate for a marker that I will reference by the marker's id.

Is this possible?  If so, let's say that the id of the marker is U123.  How would I do this?

Here is the code I use to add an event to the polygon click:
    google.maps.event.addListener(assetPolygons[polygon_count],'click', function (event) {new google.maps.event.trigger('U123', 'click');});

U123 is the name of the marker id.  The above is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

marker.setValues({id: 1}); // v3 

marker.metadata = {type: "point", id: 1}; //v2 or v3
```

I guess the better way to do this is to store your marker in a global var and then do

```
$(".something").click(function(){
new google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' );
// Here marker is a global var so accessible everywhere.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two seconds in google found [How to trigger the onclick event of a marker on a Google Maps V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730929/how-to-trigger-the-onclick-event-of-a-marker-on-a-google-maps-v3)

The only difference in the function that was stated to work, wich is:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
```

and yours that i can see is the **new**, try removing it

Answer (score 0):

I built a function that loops through the assetMarkers array that stores each marker.  This works:

```
function ClickMarker(u) {
 for (i=0;i<assetMarkers.length;i++) {
  if (assetMarkers[i].id == u) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(assetMarkers[i], 'click');
   i = assetMarkers.length;
  }
 }
}
```

In the above function, the variable u is the id of the marker in the array assetMarkers (which is the array storing the map markers).  When I create the marker, I set the id using marker.setValues({id: 'U123'}); where U123 is the id of the marker.

I have to loop through the assetMarkers array to find the one I am looking for.

I was hoping, the equivalent of document.getElementById(u) would exist in Google Maps so that I would not have to loop through the array.  It would be great, Google API guys, if we programmers could do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(google.maps.getElementById(u), 'click');
```

Thanks for everyone's input!  It was very helpful as I am a newbie to Google Maps.